# Magento contact form gives 404 page on submit?

Tags: magento, contact-form

I searched the net to find a solution for this, but all I could find does not work in my case. I have a contact CMS page under https://example.com/contact-us.

The form displays fine. When I fill in data and hit the submit button, it gives me the 404 error.

I tried all possible URLs for the form URL, but none of them worked so far. This is what I am currently using:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="https://example.com/index.php/contacts/index/post/" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Could the https be the problem? If not, what else could I try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

or

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="{{store direct_url='contacts'}}/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Please notice form_action.

Comment: can you post your website's URL?